# Entity Framework 5.0 designer can't find database connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, app-config, entity-framework-5

I have an EF 5.0 model that has been generated from the database.  This model exists in a class library project.  This class library project has an app.config file that contains the connection string information for the model.

Whenever I choose "Update model from database", I have to reenter the connection string.  It doesn't seem to see the string from the app.config file.

Also, during the model update, if I click to save the connection string in the app.config, it never does.

Here is my app.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mapEntities"
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/mapModel.csdl|
                                                       res://*/mapModel.ssdl|
                                                       res://*/mapModel.msl;
                                           provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client
                                           provider connection string=
                                               &quot;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myserver.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYDB)));User Id=MYUSERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

How do I make EF see the connection string from the app.config?  I need to add a function import to the model and I can't because it says that no connection has been configured for the model.

**EDIT**
Well I found a solution, abeit a hacky one.

[See this stackoverflow post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413220/entity-framework-losing-binding-to-connection-string-in-visual-studio).

The OP stated that he recreated a new EDMX file in the project, and that fixed it.  I did the same, it did.  I did not regenerate my old EDMX file.  I just created a new one, and then went back to the old EDMX and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the connectionString section to your web.config file.

Comment: It's already there.  I don't need it to connect during application run time.  This is during design time that I need it to connect.

Comment: Yes, usually when I've seen this happen, it is because the connection string doesn't exist in either web.config or in app.config for the project where your .edmx is located. Usually, it is because it's not in app.config and reading your question again, it seems that it is missing there. You may have to add i there manually, from the sound of it.